# Applying cases to act() in scala

Tags: scala

I was wondering how to apply a match and case to my act() method. This is my tempObject class

```
case class tempObject(typeOfData: Int) {}
```

And this is my Actor:

```
object StorageActor extends Actor {

  def act(TO: tempObject) = TO match {

    case TO(0) => println("True")
    case TO(1) => println("False")

  }
}
```

So, what should happen is, when I pass an object to act(), it calls the desired method, depending upon the values inside of the object. Is the above code correct to perform what I desire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `act` method on the `Actor` class is not supposed to be called with a value. It picks the values form the actor's mailbox and works on them. The correct way to do it is this:

```
case class TempObject(typeOfData: Int)

object StorageActor extends Actor {
  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case TempObject(0) => println("True")
        case TempObject(1) => println("False")
      }
    }
  }
}

StorageActor.start
StorageActor ! TempObject(0)
StorageActor ! TempObject(1)
```